# Installing Sonar and Jenkins on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, sonarqube

I have a tomcat server and I wish to install Jenkins and Sonar on it. I am on a debian distibution, therefore I got tomcat6 and Jenkins via apt-get. When I copy the jenkins.war to my tomcat6/webapps directory, everything runs fine. However when I copy the sonar.war to tomcat6/webapps, sonar works fine, but jenkins throws an error 500:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/jenkins/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.435.jar!/hudson/model/View/index.jelly:39:43: <st:include> PermGen space
    org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyClassTearOff.serveIndexJelly(JellyClassTearOff.java:112)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet.handleIndexRequest(JellyFacet.java:124)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:550)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:646)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:612)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:646)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:477)
    org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:159)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:95)
    hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:87)
    hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:47)
    hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
    hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
```

I've also install the manager (tomcat6-admin) and the manager is failing too when i add the sonar.war.

I've installed sonar by downloading it from codehaus, setting the database configuration and building the war.

Does anyone know why this is happening and might have a solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your exception, it appears :

```
PermGen space
org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyClassTearOff.serveIndexJelly(JellyClassTearOff.java:112)
```

There's a problem with the permgen :

> This error occurs when the JVM runs out of space in the permanent generation heap

To fix the error, you need to put the `-XX:MaxPermSize=<Y>m` (where `<Y>` is the memory you want) in the CATALINA_OPTS environment variable.

How do you achieve this ? Follow this article (for example) :

[How can I increase memory in my application server ?](http://wiki.webratio.com/index.php/How_can_I_increase_memory_in_my_application_server%3F)

Answer (score 1):

I had this configured on a RHEL server with 8Gb RAM. I found I needed (in `catalina.sh` or the non-interactive shell running tomcat) VM options of `-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

I also needed to reset the Executor `maxThreads`, and `minSpareThreads` in the conf/server.xml file (400, and 50 respectively), otherwise the server crawled.

By the way, if you're using Virtual Servers, you could try an already configured VM, [SecureCI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/secureci/), which sets up a complete Maven/Jenkins/Sonar CI environment out of the box. There's no configuration if your build relies on Maven.