# How to pass a system property to a web application hosted in Tomcat 7 running as a Windows Service?

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

There are numerous places on the Internet, suggesting that it is easily achieved by any (or all) of the following methods:

1. through `CATALINA_OPTS`
2. through `JAVA_OPTS`
3. through `TOMCAT_OPTS`
4. by placing the `set` statements in the **setenv.bat** file inside the tomcat's bin folder

My problem, is that I have tried all of the above and my web application still does not see my system property!

Here is what I am doing:

1. Stop tomcat7 service
2. set `CATALINA_OPTS=-Dabc.def=true` in the system environment
3. set `JAVA_OPTS=-Dabc.def=true` in the system environment
4. set `TOMCAT_OPTS=-Dabc.def=true` in the system environment
5. put all of the above into **c:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\setenv.bat** (seems totally redundant, but just in case)
6. Start tomcat7 service
7. Inspect the environment of the tomcat7 process using the Process Explorer tool - the environment is correct, I do see both `CATALINA_OPTS` and `JAVA_OPTS` and `TOMCAT_OPTS` equal to `-Dabc.def=true`
8. run my web app, which is a simple servlet dumping all the system properties to the response stream - **`abc.def` is not amongst them**

Please, put me out of my misery and tell me how to do it.

Comment: I don't know about the process explorer or anything, but can you see the full command line of the invoked JVM process? Does it contain the above?

Comment: I suppose by the JVM process you mean tomcat7.exe, because there is no java.exe process. And the command line will not tell you much, it is **"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\Tomcat7.exe" //RS//Tomcat7**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the Tomcat service, startup settings are stored in the registry under `Options` key at:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat<X>\Parameters\Java`

(substitute appropriate Tomcat version where needed).

Edit:

On 64-bit Windows, the registry key is:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat<X>\Parameters\Java`

even if Tomcat is running under a 64-bit JVM.

Comment: You are my savior. Only in my case the path is **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat7\Parameters\Java**, although this is strange, since tomcat7 is installed into **C:\Program Files**, rather than into **C:\Program Files (x86)** and Process Explorer reports it as a 64 bits image. Anyway, it works - thanks.

Comment: @mark Wow, thanks for that.  I'm working on an installer right now and this has saved me compatibility issues with 64-bit Windows I would have had later.  Updated answer with your info.

Comment: That's useless on a proper operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is almost 9 years old but thought someone might find this useful.

Although @prunge and @mark answers were very accurate and following their logic I was able to add system properties to my tomcat 7 instance running on Windows, there is an easier way.

In the installation directory of Tomcat there is an exe you can run called

```
%INSTALL_DIRECTORY%\bin\tomcat7w.exe
```

This opens up a Tomcat properties windows where you can control the service i.e. start and stop tomcat and there is a tab (Java) that allows you to set the Java properties as well

[image]

Scroll to the end of that panel under "Java Options" and add your system properties

```
-Dpropertyname=value
```

Then navigate back to the General tab and restart tomcat

I have tested this and my grails app now can see my properties. I use the following Groovy code to get the property out

```
System.properties.getProperty("propertyname")
```

Adding the system properties in the Windows registry showed up in this window as well so its one and the same thing, just this application seems to me to be slightly more convenient.

Hope this helps someone else

Comment: That's useless on a proper operating system.