# How to assign admin role to root

Tags: youtrack

I've removed the 'Admin' role from root and noone has the permissions to put it back! Is there a way to assign the admin role to root on the command line or somewhere else outside of the application (UI)?

This is a Windows 7 installation and YouTrack is running as a Windows Service.

Answer (score 2):

I've succeeded with restore reset password for youtrack windows 5.1.2 setting up -Djetbrains.charisma.restoreRootPassword=true on the key "Options" in the registry

Edit:

On 64-bit Windows, the registry key is:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\YouTrack\Parameters\Java

32bit Windows
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\YouTrack\Parameters\Java

Thanks to the guy from 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8610301/1384477

Answer (score 0):

About your only option as far as I'm aware is to boot into a live environment and edit the user:groups files manually, assuming the file system isn't encrypted.

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking! I'm running this locally on Win7 (as a service) at the moment so accessing the files shouldn't be a problem. I've found the YouTrack folder any pointers on where to go from there?

Comment: It'll depend what distribution you're referring to, but this might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/29004/regain-sudo-rights-after-removing-from-admin-group

Comment: I read the post but makes little sense to me as it's linux/unix. I'll read again and see if I can translate to windows world. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah sorry, after seeing your edit, I can't be much help. I assumed a unix environment with seeing you refer to it as "root".

Comment: The windows version comes preloaded with 'root' as a user. I should of mentioned windows in original question! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

On windows installation you can try the following:

1. Stop YouTrack service
2. Navigate to `${YOUTRACK_HOME}/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml`. Backup it.
3. Modify config file as follows:

   ```
   <web-app>
     <display-name>YouTrack</display-name>
     <servlet>
       <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>jetbrains.charisma.main.ServletImpl</servlet-class>
       <!-- Add this parameter -->
       <init-param>
         <param-name>jetbrains.charisma.restoreRootPassword</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <!-- End -->
       ...
     </servlet>
     ...
   </web-app>
   ```
4. Now start YouTrack, your root account should have everything reset to default, including credentials and permissions.

It makes sense to restore the config file back to initial state afterwards, not to have your account reset on every application restart.

Comment: I don't have a folder at ${YOUTRACK_HOME}/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/. I do have a web.xml file in ${YOUTRACK_HOME}\conf but it does not contain and servlet element named MainServlet.

Comment: FYI - I do have C:\Program Files\YouTrack\webapps but it only contains a single file called ROOT.war

Comment: \conf\web.xml is a different one, it won't help us here. You probably have a youtrack version, which still has application packed as WAR. No problem with that, just unpack ROOT.war (it's actually a zip file), desired WEB-INF/web.xml is inside. Edit, pack it back and start the service.

Comment: Did as you said, no joy (root still has old password and no permissions). I also tried adding -Djetbrains.charisma.restoreRootPassword=true into the java startup params and still no joy. While fiddling I seem to have killed the app completely (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cookie name "YTJSESSIONID " is a reserved token). Having serious reservations about this product :( Thanks for all of your help though