# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found after applying log rotation using log4j

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8, tomcat-juli

I'm trying to do log rotation in Tomcat 8.5. I have followed log4j process by referring URL https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j .
But after following the process mentioned in the URL I'm unable to open localhost, it's giving 404 error and the log is like below. Can anyone help me out in this?

```
"ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase- ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1125)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1858)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/WebappProperties
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4943)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 10 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.WebappProperties
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 23 more"
```

Comment: Can you summarize what you did: did you just change `logging.properties`? It seems like you removed `tomcat-juli.jar` from Tomcat's classpath or from the `bin` folder.

Comment: Here I have removed the logging .properties and also overwrite juli jar with another one which support log4j concept.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the documentation for Tomcat 7.0. The documentation for your version is available [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j).

The `tomcat-juli-extras` you downloaded for Tomcat 7.0 does not work with Tomcat 8.5 and there is no `tomcat-juli-extras` provided for Tomcat 8.5. In Tomcat 8.5 is no longer necessary (and possible) to physically replace the default JULI implementation.

**Restore** the `tomcat-juli.jar` that came with Tomcat to resolve the error.

If you want to Log4j2 as the server's logging system, follow the instructions in [Log4j2 documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-appserver/index.html). Basically you need to:

1. Create a folder for Log4j2 libraries and configuration. Let's say `$CATALINA_BASE/log4j/lib` and `$CATALINA_BASE/log4j/conf`.
2. Download [`log4j-api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.14.1), [`log4j-core`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.14.1) and [`log4j-appserver`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-appserver/2.14.1) (the latter contains an implementation of the logging API in `tomcat-juli.jar`) into `log4j/lib`,
3. Add a configuration file in you favorite format to `log4j/conf` (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)),
4. Add the three libraries from point 2 and the `log4j/conf` folder to the server's **system** classloader. This step depends on how do you start Tomcat. If you use `catalina.sh/startup.sh` (on Unixes) add to `$CATALINA_BASE/setenv.sh` (create it if necessary):

```sh
CLASSPATH="$CATALINA_BASE/log4j/lib/*.jar:$CATALINA_BASE/log4j/conf"
```

5. Restart the server.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you please explain how to do step 4 in windows? Do I need to create setenv.bat file?

Comment: On Windows you probably use the Procrun (see picture in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62346565/11748454)). There is a text field there to add these entries to the classpath.